# Erro on AChartEngine (line graph)

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I have a problem on a graph where adding the graphic layout presents an exception that I can not solve. Using `getBarChartView ()` works, but when I change to `getLineChartView` the problem happens. Below an example.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final GraphicalView gv =createIntent();       
        RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.lytGraficoVendaDiariaBarra);   
        rl.addView(gv);                
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public GraphicalView createIntent() {
        String[] titulos = new String[] { "Valor Faturado" };       
        int[] colors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#0066FF")};        
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        List<double[]> valores = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        valores.add(new double[] { 5230, 7300, 9240, 10230, 11300, 10040});
        renderer.setXLabels(1);   
        renderer.setYLabels(10);    
        renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "01/12");  
        renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "02/12");   
        renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "03/12");  
        renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "04/12");   
        renderer.addXTextLabel(5, "05/12");   
        renderer.addXTextLabel(6, "06/12");    
        renderer.addXTextLabel(7, "07/12");    
        int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();   
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {     
            SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);   
            seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);           
        }

//        final GraphicalView grfv = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getBaseContext(), buildBarDataset(titulos, valores), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
        final GraphicalView grfv = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), buildBarDataset(titulos, valores), renderer);

        return grfv; 
        }    

    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();     
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);      
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);     
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(10);             
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);     
        renderer.setBarSpacing(1);      
        renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E0E0"));      
        renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);       
        renderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.BLACK);                  
        renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);     
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FBFBFC"));       
        renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);        
        renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true); 
        int length = colors.length;     
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {         
            SimpleSeriesRenderer col = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();          
            col.setColor(colors[i]);                
            col.setChartValuesSpacing(15);  
            renderer.addSeriesRenderer(col);     
        }       
        setChartSettings(renderer, "Vendas Diárias", "Dias", "Valores", 0.5, 12.5, 0, 24000, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);     
        return renderer;     
        }       
    protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titulos, List<double[]> valores) {   
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();     
        int length = titulos.length;    
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {  
            CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titulos[i]);    
            double[] v = valores.get(i);       
            int seriesLength = v.length;      
            for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {   
                series.add(v[k]);        
                }           
            dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());     
            }         
        return dataset;     
    }   
    protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle, String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,              int labelsColor) {         
        renderer.setChartTitle(title);      
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);  
        renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);      
        renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);     
        renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);        
        renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);        
        renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);     
        renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);      
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 30, 40, 10, 40 });     
        renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);      
        renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);                       
    }   
}
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lytGraficoVendaDiariaBarra"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and what is this exception? what is said problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copied `buildBarDataset()` and `buildBarRenderer()` from the AChartEngine demo. Use `buildDataset()` and `buildRenderer()` for the line chart.